# Improve performance of Highcharts line chart

Tags: javascript, performance, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create a zoomable line chart that has 1440 data points, here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rmayx6/) thereof.

In Firefox, the performance of the chart is very sluggish, it takes several seconds to render, and there's a long delay between hovering over a datapoint and the tooltip appearing. On my page there are several such charts and their combined impact makes the page almost unusable.

Are there any tricks/tips for improving the performance of charts that have relatively large data sets? I've appended the chart's JSON to the end of this post (with the data itself truncated).

Incidentally, before I added the `turboThreshold: 0` property the chart didn't render at all because the series has more than 1000 data points. According to [the docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.turboThreshold):

> When a series contains a data array that is longer than this, only one dimensional arrays of numbers, or two dimensional arrays with x and y values are allowed. Also, only the first point is tested, and the rest are assumed to be the same format. This saves expensive data checking and indexing in long series. Set it to 0 disable. Defaults to 1000.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 10,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return currencySymbol + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                }
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + currencySymbol + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidthPlus: 0
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{"y":93,"x":1412722800000},{"y":54,"x":1412722860000}],
            turboThreshold: 0
        }]
    });
});
```

### Update

I've [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rmayx6/1/) to include all suggestions I've received so far. Disabling animations helped a bit, but the page is still very sluggish in Firefox (which is the main browser I'm targeting). I've started a bounty in the hope of attracting further suggestions.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand sluggish, it kind of is a relative term. Is there anything specific behavior that is making the chart appear sluggish? If you define certain behaviors we can tackle them more easily than abstract things like sluggishness

Comment: By "sluggish", I mean that the page is not very reponsive

Comment: Sluggish and responsive are very subjective. What i was trying to say was if you can make your question more objective, say you have a ctq that page should load in 1s or the tooltip load time be 200ms, etc. Something measurable.

Comment: The chart comes up fast in my firefox but tooltips indeed are v slow. Have you timed how long it takes to run the tooltip formatting? You could use console.time() and .timeEnd() to run some iterations and average. A pretty good formatting library can be found in d3 (free!)

Comment: Try changing `turboThreshold` option which is available inside `plotOptions > line > turboThreshold`. Set it to 1440

Answer (score 7):

I have found that animation can impact chart load times for large data sets. Try disabling animation:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation:false,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidthPlus: 0
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I would add to this that shadows on chart elements also can slow down rendering with many points.

Comment: Shadows are disabled by default. I've disabled the series animation and it noticeably improves the loading behaviour, but the page is still very sluggish once the chart has loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Here you can find [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#optimize-performance) answering your question.

Additional note: Big performance boost you will get while disabling tooltip.

Or just use Highstock, which has implemented `dataGrouping`, for example [chart with 52k of points](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping).

Comment: I've followed all relevant suggestions in the FAQ, i.e. disabled point markers and shadows (the latter are disabled by default). Unfortunately, I can't remove the tooltips. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Still, Highstock sounds like the best solution, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8rmayx6/2/ - you got navigator which allows you to browse the data. Points are approximated to get better performance and once zoomed in you can view real data.

Comment: I agree, it looks like a really good solution, but I'd need to buy a commercial license to use it, which would cost $3,000

Comment: Then to use Highcharts you need license which costs $1,500. I guess if you will contact with sales team then they should help you with upgrading license from Highcharts to Highstock. Anyway, you can try to adapt [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) example with some limitation on a bottom chart (e.g. number of points) to get better performance.

Comment: I would need to use Highcharts and Highstock because I'm using some other charts in Highcharts that don't exist in Highstock, so it really would cost me an extra $3,000. Thanks for the master-detail chart link.

Comment: Highstock contains all features developed in Highcharts. Only constructor is different: `$("#container").highcharts('StockChart', options)` vs `$("#container").highcharts(options)`. You don't need separate license for Highcharts and Highstock.

Comment: Are you sure about this? For example, if you look at the list of chart types in the Highstock demos there's no Gauge or Heatmap http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure about this, see [this page](http://www.highcharts.com/about) ;). And we have note in [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#highstock-features-in-highcharts) about Highstock including Highcharts.

Comment: I agree with Powel, you should consider Highstock or a Master Detail Highchart

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion, but I dont know if you like this. I needed charts with multiple axis and every axis has 1440 datapoints (they can only be 0 or 1 in my case) and they work fine. What I had to do for this is to change the x-axis datatype and generate the date 'manualy'.

Create categories on the x-axis with the date:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['00:00', '00:01', '00:02', '00:03',  ..., '23:59']
```

Then every datapoint is ordered the same as the category:

```
series: [{
    data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., null]
```

I know this is messy but when you do this you can reduce the data array to just the y-axis value and the rendering takes less time. [See JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jzmx5dgd/)